# Elasticsearch basics : transportclient or not?

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2

I set up a graylog stack (graylog / ES/ Mongo) everything went smooth (well almost), yesterday I tried to get some info using the following command :

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/process?pretty'
{
  "cluster_name" : "log_server_graylog",
  "nodes" : {
    "Znz_72SZSyikw6DEC4Wgzg" : {
      "name" : "graylog-27274b66-3bbd-4975-99ee-1ee3d692c522",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9350",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
      "version" : "2.4.4",
      "build" : "fcbb46d",
      "attributes" : {
        "client" : "true",
        "data" : "false",
        "master" : "false"
      },
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 788,
        "mlockall" : false
      }
    },
    "XO77zz8MRu-OOSymZbefLw" : {
      "name" : "test",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
      "version" : "2.4.4",
      "build" : "fcbb46d",
      "http_address" : "127.0.0.1:9200",
      "process" : {
        "refresh_interval_in_millis" : 1000,
        "id" : 946,
        "mlockall" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I does look like (to me at least that there is 2 nodes running, someone on the ES IRC told me that there might be a transport client running (which show up as a second node)...

I really don't understand why where this transport client comes from, also, the guy from IRC told me it used to be a common setup (using transport client) but this is discouraged now, how can I reverse the config to follow ES best practices ? (which I couldn't find on the docs)

FYI, my config file :

cat  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: log_server_graylog

```
node.name: test
path.data: /tt/elasticsearch/data
path.logs: /tt/elasticsearch/log
network.host: 127.0.0.1
action.destructive_requires_name: true
# Folowing are useless as we are defining swappiness to 1, this shloud prevent ES memeory space from being sawpped, unless emergency
#bootstrap.mlockall: true
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer using the graylog IRC, the second client is the graylog client created by.... Graylog server :)

So everything is normal and as expected.